# React js app sidebar selected item not highlighted

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router, styled-components

I created this react app with a side bar, and it looks pretty good, but one thing I can't figure out is how to mark the item (page link) that was clicked.

Here is the code, I added `activeClassName="selected"` to the SidebarLink const, and added it to the styled-component, but it's not working.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";

const SidebarLink = styled(Link)`
  /*border: 3px solid green;*/
  display: flex;
  color: #e1e9fc;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  height: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  
  &:hover {
    background: #252831;
    border-left: 4px solid #ffbc2e;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .selected {
    color: red;
  }
`;
  
const SidebarLabel = styled.span`
  margin-left: 16px;
`;

/* Used for Training dropdown */
const DropdownLink = styled(Link)`
  /*border: 3px solid red;*/
  background: #252831;
  height: 60px;
  padding-left: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  
  &:hover {
    background: #48526F;
    border-left: 4px solid #ffbc2e;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
`;

const SubMenu = ({ item }) => {
  const [subnav, setSubnav] = useState(false);
  
  const showSubnav = () => setSubnav(!subnav);
  
  return (
    <>
      <SidebarLink to={item.path} onClick={item.subNav && showSubnav} activeClassName="selected" exact>
        <div className="sidebarTextContainer">
          <div className="sidebarIcon">{item.icon}</div>
          <div className="sidebarText"><SidebarLabel>{item.title}</SidebarLabel></div>
        </div>
        <div>
          {item.subNav && subnav
            ? item.iconOpened
            : item.subNav
            ? item.iconClosed
            : null}
        </div>
      </SidebarLink>
      {subnav &&
        item.subNav.map((item, index) => {
          return (
              <DropdownLink to={item.path} key={index}>
                {item.icon}
                <SidebarLabel>{item.title}</SidebarLabel>
              </DropdownLink>
          );
        })}
    </>
  );
};
  
export default SubMenu;
```

Anyone got any idea please on how to fix this?

Comment: are you using react-router-dom v5 or v6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you're asking about remembering which item was clicked, I think what you actually want is that the link corresponding to the current page be highlighted as active.

If you're using react-router v6, you should use `NavLink` instead of `Link` ([docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/nav-link)).

> A `<NavLink>` is a special kind of `<Link>` that knows whether or not it is "active".
> By default, an `active` class is added to a `<NavLink>` component when it is active.

You should update the imported component and remove the `activeClassName`.

```
const SidebarLink = styled(NavLink)`
  // ...
  &.active {
    color: red;
  }
`

// ...

<SidebarLink to={item.path} onClick={item.subNav && showSubnav} exact>
  ...
</SidebarLink>
```

---

If you're using react-router v5, then you should also use `NavLink` but you have to pass the `activeClassName`, like you do in your example. In this case you simply need to substitute `Link` for `NavLink`.

Also note that you nested CSS syntax is incorrect. It is applied to the children of `SidebarLink`, not on `SidebarLink` itself. You'd want to replace `.selected { color: red; }` with `&.selected { color: red }`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am using react-router v6 and confirmed the solution.